# How can I rewrite this code assigning a List of String to a Collection of an Object of String?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, arraylist, observablecollection

How may I rewrite this code to assign the elements of an array list to the elements of an object at once?

```
List<string> fileEntries = new List<string>
(Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries("/storage/emulated/0/Download"));

FileLogs = new ObservableCollection<FileLog> { };

foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
{
    FileLogs.Add(new FileLog { File = fileName });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?:

```
FileLogs = new ObservableCollection<FileLog>(
    Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries("/storage/emulated/0/Download")
        .Select(fileName => new FileLog { File = fileName })
);
```

It creates an `ObservableCollection<FileLog>` using the constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<FileLog>` in a single statement.

It uses the LINQ `Select` method to transform the `IENumerable<string` returned from `Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries` into an `IEnumerable<FileLog>`.

Comment: let me try it in my program. there are more than one file in FileSystemEntries. i just don't know how to assign from the files list to my objects list.

Comment: @zawhtut: Like I showed you. This code will add a `FileLog` per string returned from the `Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries` into the `ObservableCollection<FileLog>`.

Comment: So. Is there also a way without using LINQ? Basically it cannot convert `IEnumerable<string> to IEnumerable<FileLog>. FileLog object only has one string type element. Just curious.

Comment: Without LINQ you have to iterate through the `IEnumerable<string>` manually using a loop. That's that the LINQ method does for you.